# How to covert $xyz$ value to speed?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

There is a sensor (accelerometer) on pedal of indoor bike which sends out $xyz$ value and we want to convert them to cycling speed but we just can't.

It has a default of $5$ speed when not moving. And when we move upward it goes up to $> 5$,  but when it goes down it goes down to $0$.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWeKD.jpg

For example $y = 5$ default (not moving).
We cycle the pedal, we are going up, the speed goes up to $10$
We continue cycling, its now going down
it goes $y = 0$
BUT
If we are at high speed example $25$ is going up
Then going down would be around $12$
Thats how its behaviour is

We have $x, y, z$ values and we are getting the magnitudes which are the speeds on the picture

We need to find a way to have a constant speed when cycling down based on the current behaviour on the image

Comment: Are you saying you want to convert the 3 accelerations on the x,y,and z axes into a rotational speed? That's a very complex and questionable setup because of the continual change in direction which isn't going to be consistent because of the "ankling" factor of a rider. . Surely this would be easier to mount to the crank arm and align one of the axes in the radial direction of the crank arm for a single reading to be converted via a centripetal algorithm. I'm sure that's what they must use on these hub mounted speed sensors.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how you mean by ankling, but is there any solution if  I put it on pedal?